# task with number of task can run along that in celery

Tags: python, multithreading, celery, celery-task

As I see in celery, It can get number of tasks for a worker, that can run them at a same time.

I need run a task and set number of tasks can run simultaneously with this task.

[image: celery with workers]

Therefore, If I set this number to 2 and this task send to worker with 10 threads,
worker can run just one another task.

Answer (score 1):

Worker will reserve tasks for each worker's tread. If you want to limit the number of tasks worker can execute the same time, you should configure your concurrency (e.g. to limit 1 task at the time, you need worker with 1 process `-c 1`).

You can also check prefetch configuration, but it only defines the number of tasks reserved for each process of the worker.

Here is Celery documentation where prefetch configuration explained:
http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/optimizing.html

Comment: Is there any way to dynamic change number of worker process?

Comment: You can start/stop additional workers any time you want.
Also it might be possible to change worker's pool to increase/decrease the number of processes for the particular worker, but I can answer how it's better to do. You can refer to this question, maybe it will be helpful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956272/dynamically-add-remove-threads-to-the-worker-pool-in-celery

Also Celery documentation on workers:
http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html